# Python TypeError: ("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Tags: python, pandas

Python TypeError: ("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"
Python TypeError: ("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

Answer (score 0):

x must be None for some of the things you are processing. Add something like

```
if math.isnan(x):
    return "0"
```

and the error will go away. Fundamentally, it seems like your dataset might need to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to empty strings("" is the empty string) in NRIC_second column, because length of empty string is 0. There might be some None values in that column. The dataset needs to be cleaned up.